# How to save a new excel worksheet to variable location based on a cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I try to set up a code that will save a excelworksheet in a workbook as a PDF and will extract one other worksheet and saves that one under a different name in the same location. atm my code works except for the part that it saves the file not always to the right location.

I use an excel formula to get the right filepath in cell "Dimensionering!I8". I save the worksheet in the same location as the workbook is allready saved.

In the second part of the code I copy a worksheet to a new workbook so I linked the filepath from the worksheet 'dimensionering' to the worksheet 'offertetekst'.

```
Sub SAVE()


    Dim filename As String
    Dim filename1 As String

    filename = Range("Dimensionering!C8")

    Sheets("offerte stuklijst").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$18:$A$1731").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1"
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
    Chdir Range("Dimensionering!I8")
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=filename & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

    filename1 = Range("Offerte_tekst!E1491")

    Sheets("Offerte_tekst").Select
    Sheets("Offerte_tekst").Copy
    Chdir Range("Offerte_tekst!E1492")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=filename1 & ".xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    filename:=Sheets("Dimensionering").Range("I8").Value & "\" & filename & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Sheets("Offerte_tekst").Range("E1492").Value & "\" & filename1 & ".xlsx" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

This assumes you don't have backslash in your path cell `Dimensionering!I8`